# How to check whether an int variable contains a legal (not trap representation) value?

Tags: c++, integer, language-lawyer, data-representation, bit-representation

#### Context:

This is mainly a followup to [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59615243/3545273). OP wanted to guess whether a variable contained an int or not, and my first thought was that in C (as in C++) an int variable could only contain an int value. And Eric Postpischil reminded me that *trap representations* were allowed per standard for the int type...

Of course, I know that most modern system only use 2-complement representations of integers and no padding bits, meaning that no trap representation can be observed. Nevertheless both standards seem to still allow for 3 representations of signed types: sign and magnitude, one's complement and two's complement. And at least C18 draft (n2310 6.2.6 Representations of types) explicitely allows padding bits for integer types other that char.

#### Question

So in the context of possible padding bits, or non two's complement signed representation, `int` variables could contain trap values for conformant implementations. Is there a reliable way to make sure that an int variable contains a valid value?

Comment: I know that C and C++ are different languages and have different standard reference documents. But here I would be interested by both and their possible differences. If the differences are either too important or if it could mess answers, I can specialize this question for one and ask a different one for the other language.

Comment: If it were possible to observe it, it wouldn't be called a trap. Or at least it wouldn't be *right* to call it a trap.

Comment: You can always `memcpy` the `int` to `char[sizeof int]`, then do platform-specific inspection of the bit values...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++'s current working draft (for C++20), an integer cannot have a trap representation. An integer is mandated as two's complement: ([basic.fundamental]/3)

> An unsigned integer type has the same object representation, value representation, and alignment requirements ([basic.align]) as the corresponding signed integer type.
>   For each value x of a signed integer type, the value of the corresponding unsigned integer type congruent to x modulo 2N has the same value of corresponding bits in its value representation. 41
>   [ Example: The value −1 of a signed integer type has the same representation as the largest value of the corresponding unsigned type.
>   — end example
>    ]

Where the note 41 says

> This is also known as two's complement representation.

This was changed in [p0907](https://wg21.link/p0907).

Additionally, padding bits in integers cannot cause traps: ([basic.fundamental/4])

> Each set of values for any padding bits ([basic.types]) in the object representation are alternative representations of the value specified by the value representation.
>   [ Note: Padding bits have unspecified value, but do not cause traps.
>   See also ISO C 6.2.6.2.
>   — end note
>    ]

Comment: Thank you! I could not find the reference for the C++20 draft. Do you know a pdf version publicly available?

Comment: I usually browse the online version at http://eel.is/c++draft/, which includes navigable links and is up to date with the latest TeX files. You can otherwise find the last published working draft at https://wg21.link/std. (In fact, https://wg21.link/ is just a useful link in general to access papers and things.)

Comment: @SergeBallesta : [Working Draf](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/)